# Got dimension error for input (n,n,1) vs. (n,n) even after explicit definition

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I have two greyscale image input (both are 256 x 256 image), and I put them under `filename1` and `filename2`. When I put these two image into a placeholder under `feed`, I already mentioned that the shape is `[None, 256, 256, 1]`.

However, when I run the below code, I still got an error, saying that my current input is `(256,256)` instead of `(256,256,1)`. How should I modify my code?

My code:-

```
feed = {
          tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 256, 256, 1]): misc.imread(filename1),
          tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 256, 256, 1]): misc.imread(filename2)
        }

sess.run(graph.get_tensor_by_name("output:0"), feed_dict=feed)
```

Error I got:-

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (256, 256) for Tensor u'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 256, 256, 1)'
```

---

Updated

I tested this as well, and got error as below:-

```
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tag_constants.TRAINING], export_dir)

    img1 = misc.imread(filename1, flatten=True)
    img2 = misc.imread(filename2, flatten=True)

    feed = {
      tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 256, 256, 1]): img1[np.newaxis, :, :, np.newaxis],
      tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 256, 256, 1]): img2[np.newaxis, :, :, np.newaxis]
    }

    graph = tf.get_default_graph()

    sess.run(graph.get_tensor_by_name("output:0"), feed_dict=feed)
```

Error that I got:-

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'data' with dtype float and shape [?,256,256,1]
```

Comment: is the problem maybe your first dimension? try passing `[misc.imread(filename1)]` instead of the single array. It worked for me on a similar case in the past.

Answer (score 0):

(256, 256) is the default shape for an array outputted by `imread` function for grayscale image. So in order to feed it to your `feed_dict` you need to

```
file = misc.imread(filename1)
arr = tf.expand_dims(file, -1)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried `tf.expand_dims(misc.imread(filename1),-1)` and `tf.expand_dims(misc.imread(filename2),-1)` in `feed`. But I got `TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles. For reference, the tensor object was Tensor("ExpandDims:0", shape=(256, 256, 1), dtype=uint8) which was passed to the feed with key Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(?, 256, 256, 1), dtype=float32)`. What should I do?

Comment: It clearly says that value should be numpy array, not tensor. You need to place this code before

Comment: In this case `file` is the value fed to TensorFlow, so it has to be a NumPy value, not a TensorFlow tensor (that is, the shape or type of `file` should be fixed with NumPy operations, not TensorFlow ones).

Answer (score 0):

[`scipy.misc.imread`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html) returns a `(256, 256)` array because the images is grayscale, so there is no need for a "channels" dimension. You can just add that dimension by yourself. You will also need to add a new first dimensions to match the first dimension of the placeholder (`None`).

In addition to that, you should make sure that you read the image in the format that you expect. Since you are working with grayscale images, you can pass `flatten=True` to [`scipy.misc.imread`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html) to ensure that the returned image is float32 and has no color channels.

```
from scipy import misc

img1 = misc.imread(filename1, flatten=True)
img2 = misc.imread(filename2, flatten=True)
feed = {
          tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 256, 256, 1]): img1[np.newaxis, :, :, np.newaxis],
          tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 256, 256, 1]): img2[np.newaxis, :, :, np.newaxis]
        }

sess.run(graph.get_tensor_by_name("output:0"), feed_dict=feed)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it, but I got `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'data' with dtype float and shape [?,256,256,1]`. How should I fix that?

Comment: I tried, but I still get the exactly same error `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'data' with dtype float and shape [?,256,256,1]`

Comment: @H42 Hum, strange, what I posted seems to work for me, if I add the missing parts (setting `filename1` and `filename2`, defining `graph` and creating an `output` tensor). Is it possible there is any difference between the snippet and what you are running?

Comment: I think it's the same. But I pasted more codes at the "edited" section above, and you can have a look. Thanks

Comment: @H42 But the error is complaining about missing value for a placeholder named `data` that is not seen in your code. And you try to evaluate the tensor `output:0`, for which we also cannot see the definition. I'm not sure it really has to do with this fragment of code.